# CommandLineToArgvW quirk

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a little win32 program that calls `CommandLineToArgvW` with the given `lpCmdLine`

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
  (void)hInstance;
  (void)hPrevInstance;
  (void)nCmdShow;
  int argc;
  LPTSTR* argv =  CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &argc);
  MessageBoxW(0, lpCmdLine, TEXT("lpCmdLine"), MB_OK    );

  for(int i=0; i<argc;++i){
    MessageBoxW(0, argv[i], TEXT("argv"), MB_OK );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the strange thing that i observe is:

- if i call the program without parameter, the `lpCmdLine` is an empty string and `CommandLineToArgvW` returns 1 argument - the executable path.
- if called with parameter, `CommandLineToArgvW` returns the exact number of parameters, without the executable

I could not find this strange behaviour documented.

What did i miss? Do I use the command in an unintended way?

Comment: It looks like you must be reading the documentation for a different function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This is documented behavior.

Per [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw):

> `lpCmdLine`
>
> Type: `LPCWSTR`
>
> Pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that contains the full command line. **If this parameter is an empty string the function returns the path to the current executable file.**

Which means `CommandLineToArgvW()` returns the calling executable name ONLY if the `lpCmdLine` parameter is null, or if it *explicitly* includes the executable name.

Note that `CommandLineToArgvW()` wants *the full command line*.  However, per [`WinMain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain):

> `lpCmdLine`
>
> Type: `LPSTR`
>
> The command line for the application, **excluding the program name**. To retrieve the **entire command line**, use the [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/08dfcab2-eb6e-49a4-80eb-87d4076c98c6) function.

So, when you execute the program without parameters, `WinMain`'s `lpCmdLine` parameter is blank, and `CommandLineToArgvW()` returns just the executable name.  But if you execute the program with parameters, the `lpCmdLine` parameter is not blank but does not include the executable name, so `CommandLineToArgvW()` returns just the parameters without the executable name.

As such, you need to do what the `WinMain()` documentation says and use `GetCommandLine()` instead of `lpCmdLine`.  This is also stated in the `CommandLineToArgvW()` documentation:

> The [`GetCommandLineW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/08dfcab2-eb6e-49a4-80eb-87d4076c98c6) function can be used to get a command line string that is suitable for use as the `lpCmdLine` parameter.

So, use this instead:

```
LPWSTR* argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
```